# Nodejs as Windows Service can't read files on network drive

Tags: node.js, windows, service, nssm

I have developped a little app in NodeJs which read and write some files. These files are stored on a shared folder of my local network. Everything was working until I tried to start NodeJs as Windows Service through NSSM (a little .exe that allows you to transform a .bat to a Windows Service).

In fact, `fs.readFile` doesn't work anymore so i can't use it, and i don't see where does the problem come from.
In addition, `fs.existsSync("\\\\10.200.10.1\\reporting\\")` returns false, but `fs.existsAsync("\\\\10.200.10.1\\reporting\\")` returns true.
I also tried some other functions like fs.access and it doesn't work either.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me how i can make this work. I don't really care about NSSM, my only goal is to make my Node App works as Windows Service, so if an other tool can resolve my issue, let's tell me.

I don't know if it's the same problem, but I have an other thing which doesn't work in service mode : [Execute VBS from Nodejs in background mode (Tasks Scheduler or Windows Service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750660/)

Comment: What is `fs.existsAsync()`?

Comment: This is the async version of fs.existsSync. I know these functions are deprecated but they are still working.

Comment: Can you show us your real code?  I ask because `fs.existsSync(\\10.200.10.1\reporting\) ` isn't legal Javascript as there's no quotes around the path name.  And, if you did have quotes around this, it would need to be `fs.existsSync("\\\\10.200.10.1\\reporting\\")` to get the escaped backslashes correct.  Windows path names are a pain in Javascript strings because of the use of backslash.

Comment: Yes it's "\\\\10.200.10.1\\reporting\\", but i actually use a variable string. And I also tried with the drive key "N:\\\\" but nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you set a logon account for your service that has proper permissions to those network resources?  Did you configure networking as a dependent service (so you're sure networking is available when your service gets started)?

Comment: If trying the `N` drive, the proper Javascript string would just be `"N:\\"`, not `"N:\\\\"`.

Comment: I tried with N:\\\ and N:\\ but the result is the same. I use the same account/password than my windows session, and i can access to it through explorer.

Comment: If you use `fs.access()` with a callback, what is the exact error you get?

Comment: I tried with another file :[2019-11-08T08:48:49.027Z] { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'I:\Passwords.xls'
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'access',
  path: 'I:\\Passwords.xls' }

Comment: With IP : [2019-11-08T08:48:49.074Z] { Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, access '\\10.200.10.1\Info\Passwords.xls'
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'access',
  path: '\\\\10.200.10.1\\Info\\Passwords.xls' }

Comment: Did you found the solution for this ? I'm having the same problems. I know there has to be some Logon permissions, but I'm not sure what user should I use for this

Comment: Sorry, i didn't found any solution for this. I noticed some problems with NodeJS in background mode, so i use now PM2 to start the app and still make it invisible. Unfortunatly, the session must be opened.

Comment: The security of your local user is different than the windows process. It doesn't have access to the passwords necessary to access shared path (UNC)